# GLSL: Why is const int array so much slower than normal array?

Tags: performance, opengl, constants, glsl

I have an OpenGL shader written in glsl. I have a globally defined array at the top of the header like this:

```
const int permutations[256] = int[256](
    64 ,  34 ,  36 , 137 , 120 , 122 , 246 ,  46 ,  79 ,  10 ,  37 , 181,
    ...
    );
```

When I start the program, it is extremely slow, meaning I have only like 1 frame per second, when displaying a simple teapot using the shader.

However, as soon as I remove the "const" from the above declaration, everything works fine, and I'm back at interactive frame rates.

So, the "problem" is actually already solved... but I was wondering, why this could be the case? Very counterintuitive, as in my experience, using consts usually makes programs *faster*.

---

### Update

I actually tried to use a Uniform first instead of the const int array, with exactly the same code everywhere else. However, in this case compiling the shader crashes with:

```
Internal error: assembly compile error for fragment shader at offset
34609:
-- error message -- line 651, column 22:  error: invalid local parameter number
```

Comment: What I do wonder is, why you put such a long array into the shader source after all. This sounds like the job for a array uniform.

Comment: @datenwolf: It's arguable. If it's const, then it's const, no point in putting it into an external buffer (and the GL should handle it as a uniform array *internally* if that's better performing). Jan: your issue is likely IHV and driver specific. Have you tried it on different hw (preferably different vendor) ?

Comment: Sounds a bit like the driver switches to software emulation because a const int array cannot be that large. Just a guess, but 1 FPS is really slow. Maybe when it's not const it uses something like a uniform array and if it's const it tries to put it into some local registers, where it just doesn't fit.

Comment: See the update on why I didn't use a uniform... actually, the driver really seems to be a bit buggy. I'm using an nvidia card with official drivers on linux, but I can't test on my other (intel) card because some extensions are missing.

Comment: If an array uniform is slow or unusable, try a 1D texture (scale the values to [0..1] before passing them to the shader).

Comment: That assembly error looks like a known problem I've seen on certain older Nvidia drivers -- you might be able to fix it (and the slowdown you are seeing) by upgrading to a newer driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's very strange. Most probably you're having driver issues. I've ran included shader code on my Nvidia 540M under windows, and let it run in cycle. In that cycle I called shader program once and measured time (also I had checked with transform feedback if shader is working correctly). Most of cycles ended in 2-3 miliseconds, with some peaks at 25 ms. However removing `const` identifier had no effect on performance. These are quite small values to measure, but from your description the performance hit of `const` should be observable even here.

```
#version 150
const int permutations[256] = int[256](
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21,
...
246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255
);

flat out int num1[32];

void main(){
    for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++){
        num1[i] = (permutations[2*i]+permutations[2*i+1])*(permutations[2*i+2]+permutations[2*i+3]);
    }
}
```

Maybe if you wouldn't mind I could try to run your program on my hardware, but it would have to be compiled for windows and please include all dynamic libraries.

Comment: It probably is a driver issue after all. Anyway, I'm finished with the project now and it doesn't really matter anymore. I was basically just wondering why something like this could happen. But thanks for the help!